# Google sheets script doesnt work unless I make a copy of it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title says, I have a script that sorts column every time I input a keyword on a cell. But this only works only when I make a copy of the script. When I close the google tab and reopen, it wont work every time. Can someone help me with this.

**Code**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A108') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}

function SortbyName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:102");
  range.sort(1);
}

function SortbyClass() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:102");
  range.sort(2);
}

function SortbyContri() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:102");
  range.sort(3);
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyAA8.jpg)

Comment: Hello @Jason, do you get any errors when executing the script? Also, what do you get if you check the execution logs? Cheers!

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: @ale13 Sorry for responding late. No, I don't get any errors, no logs too. So frustrating to open the script editor and make a copy everytime I want to use it.

Comment: @JasonJohnAbraham what about checking the **Executions** tab? What are you getting there after running the script?

Comment: @ale13 Do you mean this? https://imgur.com/xk7HRlr

Comment: Now, that I made a copy, it did what it does but I had this error on Executions tab:Jan 20, 2020, 7:42:04 PM Error TypeError: (class)@7c3a391a is not a function, it is undefined.
    at onEdit(Copy of Copy of Copy of Copy of Sort:4)

Comment: @ale13, I think this is the culprit, do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you get it seems like the error you encounter is on the `onEdit` trigger.

Therefore, you could make the following changes:

```
var regEx= /^\w+$/;
if (e.value.match(regEx)) {        
      eval(e.value);
      e.range.clear();
}
```

If you want to use **Regular Expressions** with Apps Script you have to use the `.match()` function or you could create a new `RegExp` object.

But since you are trying to do a simple sorting, you don't necessarily have to use a regular expression, you can try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:17");
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A20') {
    if (e.value == "SortbyName" ) {        
      e.range.clear();
      range.sort(1);
    }
    else if (e.value == "SortbyClass" ) {        
      e.range.clear();
      range.sort(2);
    }
    else if (e.value == "SortbyContri") {        
      e.range.clear();
      range.sort(3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this but it doesn't work: https://imgur.com/mCohQfF

Comment: Hello @Jason, what isn't it working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It just does nothing. No errors on Executions tab. After I input the value on cell A108, it just clears it, but not sorts the table.

Comment: @JasonJohnAbraham was the sorting working before? Because I think it did not. You should do the sorting **inside** the `onEdit` function or call the sorting functions inside the `onEdit` based on the kind of sorting you want.

Comment: Yes, it works when I make a copy of the script. go back to the sheet and input "SortbyName" on cell A108, but it is not working on the first time I open the sheet.

Comment: I made a sample, please check:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IbXRBk4RIVK9jAjF9UsySFpEXAxCK3hqqKfuM79D1ZY/edit?usp=sharing